# Phonegap and Django Authentication

Tags: ajax, django, cordova, tastypie, django-authentication

I am in the middle of building a [PhoneGap (Cordova)](http://phonegap.com/) app which I would like to be able to talk to a Django site of mine. The steps needed to get the app working are:

1. Authenticate the user (stay logged-in across app restarts) (e.g. get session cookie from Django for communication with the service - where to store?). **Note**: The Django endpoint uses https.
2. When app receives push notification load some data from my django site.
3. Make selection on data and submit response back to my django site (will need the csrf token?)

I was able to sort out the push notifications but now **I am wondering which solution would work best for the communication with Django**.
As I understand there are two possible approaches:

1. Either to implement a REST service with something like [tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) or
2. try to setup the communication via ajax (e.g. jQuery)

At the moment I am thinking that going simply ajax might be the best approach since the app is fairly small and there are no additional requirement for a REST API.

It would be great if anyone could give me any pointers on how to solve this or share some experiece / code. Especially the steps of the authentication process are unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is still an open question but it is sure an interesting one.
I would strongly suggest on using the [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) and you could start by using the [docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which are indeed a great point of reference.

My experience until now has shown that I should always start by making my api clear(and rest) than choosing an easier faster solution(e.g. ajax) because if your app is a successful one, frameworks like tastypie help you scale.

The authentication process is pretty straightforward if you choose the basic one.
You just ask for the user credentials and there are many clients implementing the client side basic auth.
Fortunately, tastypie supports more than this. For example, the api authentication and you could read more [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html).
If you need anything else, please let me know.

Regards,
Michael.